# Result set returns 3 rows but i am only able to print 2?

Tags: java, sql, web-applications

The code below gets the information i require from my database but is not printing out all of the information. Firstly i know it is getting all of the correct information from the table because i have tried the query in sql developer.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        conn = getConnection();
        String query = "SELECT menu.menu_id, menu_title, dish.dish_id, dish_name, dish_description, dish_price, menu.week_no "
                + "FROM menu, dish, menu_allocation "
                + "WHERE menu.active = '1' "
                + "AND menu.menu_id = menu_allocation.menu_id "
                + "AND dish.dish_id = menu_allocation.dish_id "
                + "AND menu.week_no IN (09, 10, 11)";
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        MenuList list = null;
        while (rs.next()) {
            list = new MenuList(rs);
            System.out.println(rs.getRow());
        }
        for (int pos = 0; pos < list.size(); pos++) {
            Menu menu = list.getMenuAt(pos);

            System.out.println(menu.getDescription());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
    }

}
```

The output from the terminal is as follows:

```
 3 //Number of rows
 Fish and Chips //3rd row
 Chocolate Cake //2nd row
 //Here should be 1st row
 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Even though it says there are three rows it has only printed the two. Can anybody see if there is a problem with the above?

Comment: If you have more information to add the right thing to do is to edit your question or add a comment.  Don't post something as an answer which isn't an answer as people looking at your question might not see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to be sure without seeing the code for the `MenuList` class but I don't think you need to loop over the `ResultSet` as `MenuList` does that for you.

As the `MenuList` constructor takes the `ResultSet` in `rs` as a parameter it probably loops over the `ResultSet` to create its entries.  As you've already called `rs.next()` in the `while` of your loop the `MenuList` misses the first result.

I think you should replace all this:

```
MenuList list = null;
while (rs.next()) {
    list = new MenuList(rs);
    System.out.println(rs.getRow());
}
```

With:

```
MenuList list = new MenuList(rs);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a debugger so you understand what your progam is doing.

You appear to be only keeping the last row loaded, so while you have 3 rows, you only keep the last.  It appears you are getting two values from the last row.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        conn = getConnection();
        String query = "SELECT menu.menu_id, menu_title, dish.dish_id, dish_name, dish_description, dish_price, menu.week_no "
                + "FROM menu, dish, menu_allocation "
                + "WHERE menu.active = '1' "
                + "AND menu.menu_id = menu_allocation.menu_id "
                + "AND dish.dish_id = menu_allocation.dish_id "
                + "AND menu.week_no IN (09, 10, 11)";
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        MenuList[3] list = null;
        int idx = 0;                                    //Add index
        while (rs.next()) {                     
            list[idx] = new MenuList(rs);               //use index
            idx++;                                      //increment index
            System.out.println(rs.getRow());
        }
        for (int pos = 0; pos < list.size(); pos++) {
            Menu menu = list.getMenuAt(pos);//Don't know that
                                                         //get menu by index
            System.out.println(menu.getDescription());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If this is just the same code as OP posted, please delete.  If you "fixed" it, please [edit], *describe the fix* and then *fix your formatting*.